# Swipe to Delete being tapped twice

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How do I stop the swipe to delete function from being tapped twice on my table view? Its causing crashes by trying to delete data twice, or access data already deleted.

Example of the swipe to delete functionality I'm talking about:
http://media.tumblr.com/25eb2fcf7aa2cd84f5cb27c54ca1ad5b/tumblr_inline_muotqqEYrY1qzumo9.jpg

All code relating to the swipe to delete functionality:
http://pastebin.com/5VEbPvEC

This is the code to delete:

```
//HTTP GET request to delete from server
//Then in:
DispatchQueue.main.async {
...
self.leaderboardData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

EDIT: I tried disabling user interaction as well:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

The delete event was still triggered twice.

EDIT 2:

When I tap twice I either get this crash:

```
libswiftFoundation.dylib`static Foundation.IndexPath._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC (Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSIndexPath>) -> Foundation.IndexPath:
    0x100c72914 <+0>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #-32]!
    0x100c72918 <+4>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #16]
    0x100c7291c <+8>:  add    x29, sp, #16              ; =16 
    0x100c72920 <+12>: mov    x19, x0
    0x100c72924 <+16>: cbz    x19, 0x100c7294c          ; <+56>
    0x100c72928 <+20>: mov    x0, x19
    0x100c7292c <+24>: bl     0x100c9ae14               ; function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Dead> of Foundation.IndexPath.init (nsIndexPath : __ObjC.NSIndexPath) -> Foundation.IndexPath
    0x100c72930 <+28>: mov    x20, x0
    0x100c72934 <+32>: mov    x0, x19
    0x100c72938 <+36>: bl     0x100cdc2e4               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
    0x100c7293c <+40>: mov    x0, x20
    0x100c72940 <+44>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #16]
    0x100c72944 <+48>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp], #32
    0x100c72948 <+52>: ret    
->  0x100c7294c <+56>: brk    #0x1
```

Or I see a few of these:

```
/api/leaderboards/delete/132 returned 500.
```

The 500 indicates that it failed to delete the record because there was no record.

This only occurs when I mash the delete button that appears.

EDIT 3:

I've changed my code a little, now mashing the delete button is not causing a crash, but whenever I delete the last row, I get a crash.

Code:
http://pastebin.com/57hMZQiJ

A breakpoint is triggered at line:

```
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.5.2/UITableView.m:1610
```

Thanks.

Comment: put code also here.

Comment: What code do you want to see? There is nothing specific. Its a default UITableView.

Comment: want to see your code for delete .

Comment: you can disable interactions to your screen, while you're modifying your data source

Comment: @KKRocks I updated the post. Let me know if you want to see more code. I'm not sure what else to put. Thanks.

Comment: @Misha I tried to do this with `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` immediately after the row was selected, I was still ending up with it executing the delete events :/

Comment: @toast are you experiencing the crash because you are doing the delete on a background thread?

Comment: @dirtydanee See updated post with all code. I'm not sure if its a problem because its on the background thread. Do you know?

Comment: @toast when i do you see the crash? Is your delegate being called twice automatically, or  you can tap twice on the delete button?

Comment: @dirtydanee I've updated my answer again, see edit 2. To answer your question, both lol.

Comment: try disabling touch to whole view, not cell and when your service call ends only then enable it

Comment: @Misha that didnt work either :(

Comment: can you post something ?

Comment: @Misha see edit 3. I think the mashing the delete button is solved, but now I'm having problems when I delete the last row in the table. It triggers a breakpoint. I've pasted it above.

Comment: @Misha Solved. See below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. So I had a few problems.

I was trying to disable user interaction in `didSelectRowAt`. Instead of in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` which I do now.

I think this solved the mashing on "Delete" button problem.

Then the problems where I was getting a crash only when deleting the last row came from an incorrect return value of `numRowsInSection`.

When the data array is empty I load a placeholder cell, giving the user some info about what to do. This making the app attempt to read an index that no longer exists. So I solved it by doing this:

```
self.leaderboardData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
if self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) == 1 {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
else {
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

When it gets to one, I reload the table data because my numOfRowsInSection looks like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count = 0
    if leaderboardData.count < 1 {
        count = 1
    }
    else {
        count = leaderboardData.count
    }
    return count
}
```